# JSON values getting jumbled up after parsing iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am getting an JSON response and I am serialising it using `NSJSONSerialization` in iOS **Xcode 5.1**. The o/p I am getting is:

(lldb) po jsons

```
{
    Res1 = ({
        ADDRESS = " 131 SleakField Road ";
        ALP = " ";
        "BIRTH_DATE" = "05/09/2002";
    });
    Res2 = ({
        Performance = "";
        Score = "";
    }, {
        Performance = Proficient;
        Score = 221;
    }, {
        Performance = "";
        Score = "";
    }, {
        Performance = Proficient;
        Score = 237;
    });
    Res3 = ();
    Res4 = ();
}
```

The jsons is a `NSDictionary`.

But when I am separating the keys from the above key-value pair using the below code:

```
jsonKeys = [[NSArray alloc] init];
jsonKeys = [jsons allKeys];
```

The o/p I am getting is:

(lldb) po jsonKeys

```
<__NSArrayI 0xb62dff0>(
    Res2,
    Res5,
    Res3,
    Res1,
    Res6,
    Res4
)
```

Its all jumbled up. I want it the way I am getting it from the server.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: By definition, the entries in a JSON "object" (NSDictionary) are unordered.  You want too much.

Comment: You don't need the `jsonKeys = [[NSArray alloc] init]`. That line is creating an object that'll be discarded without being used ever.

Comment: Removing jsonKeys = [[NSArray alloc] init] dint bring any change to the output.

Comment: @LeoJoseph: Of course not. It creates an array that gets immediately thrown away. Whether you create an array that gets immediately thrown away or not makes no difference, except informing other programmers about the quality of code to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from other question asked in stack overflow.

```
jsonsDictsKeys = [[jsons allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
jsonsDictsValues = [jsons objectsForKeys: jsonsDictsKeys notFoundMarker: [NSNull null]];
```

where jsonsDictsKeys and jsonsDictsValues are NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary can't do that. the entries are not ordered.

to keep the order, you should use a list of entries, changing the structure of the json

Comment: I am getting the my-value pairs in the local NSDictionary in the order I want. Now its nothing related to JSON or Serialisation. I just want to get the keys from it. [array allkeys] function should do the thing. But somehow its not.